# Flutter Firebase Pagination Problem to Scrolling Top

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, pagination

I made a social media application using Flutter Firebase, and like every social media application, I have a stream of posts shared by users on the home screen. At first, I didn't have any problems, but as the number of data increased, I started to have problems especially getting photos. Later I found out that this was because I was getting all the data at once and decided to use Pagination. I have successfully used Pagination and I also started using Cached Network Image to load my photos faster. But I still have such a problem in the flow. When I scroll the screen to the bottom, the data is loaded at the limit I set, in the example my limit is 12, so I have no problem when scrolling down the screen, but when I want to quickly scroll the screen up, it tries to load all the data again, the system is having too much difficulty, I can't load it at the end and the application gives a lost connection error and closes itself.

In my opinion, the same thing should happen when we swipe the screen up, just as the data is loaded piece by piece as much as the limit number we set when swiping down the screen.

Otherwise, this problem that I am experiencing occurs.

Do you know any solution for this?

This is my code for Pagination;

```
getData() async {
    var Ref1 = (widget.post != null)
        ? _firestore
            .collection("users")
            .doc(widget.post["profileID"])
            .collection("Datas")
            .orderBy("uploadTime", descending: true)
            .limit(perpage)
        : null;
    setState(() {
      loadingProducts = true;
    });
    var reponse = await Ref1.get();
    listt = reponse.docs;
    lastDocument = reponse.docs[reponse.docs.length - 1];
    setState(() {
      loadingProducts = false;
    });
  }

  getmoreData() async {
    if (moreDataAvailable == false) {
      return;
    }
    if (gettingmoreData == true) {
      return;
    }
    setState(() {
      gettingmoreData = true;
    });
    var Ref1 = (widget.post != null)
        ? _firestore
            .collection("users")
            .doc(widget.post["profileID"])
            .collection("Datas")
            .orderBy("uploadTime", descending: true)
            .startAfterDocument(lastDocument)
            .limit(perpage)
        : null;

    var reponse = await Ref1.get();
    if (reponse.docs.length < perpage) {
      moreDataAvailable = false;
    }
    lastDocument = reponse.docs[reponse.docs.length - 1];
    listt.addAll(reponse.docs);
    setState(() {});
    setState(() {
      gettingmoreData = false;
    });
  }
```

And this is my Builder;

```
GridView.builder(
  controller: scrollController,
  physics: ScrollPhysics(),
  gridDelegate:
      SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
    crossAxisCount: 3,
  ),
  itemCount: listt.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () =>
          navigateToDetail(listt[index]),
      child: Hero(
        tag: (listt[index]["foto"] != null)
            ? NetworkImage(
                listt[index]["foto"])
            : AssetImage(
                "assets/images/n_image.jpg"),
        child: Container(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment:
                MainAxisAlignment.end,
            children: [
              Container(
                height: size.height * 0.078,
                width: double.infinity,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius:
                        BorderRadius.only(
                      bottomRight:
                          Radius.circular(
                              10.0),
                      bottomLeft:
                          Radius.circular(
                              10.0),
                    ),
                    color: Colors.grey[600]
                        .withOpacity(0.5)),
                child: Center(
                  child: AutoSizeText(
                    "${listt[index]["name"]}",
                    textAlign:
                        TextAlign.center,
                    style: GoogleFonts.lora(
                      textStyle: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 15,
                      ),
                    ),
                    maxLines: 2,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: (listt[index]
                          ["foto"] !=
                      null)
                  ? OptimizedCacheImageProvider(
                      listt[index]["foto"])
                  : AssetImage(
                      "assets/images/n_image.jpg"),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius:
                BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
),
```

And im listening controller in initstate with this;

```
scrollController.addListener(() {
  double maxScroll = scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent;
  double currentScroll = scrollController.position.pixels;
  double delta = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.25;

  if (maxScroll - currentScroll <= delta) {
    getmoreTarif();
  }
});
```

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: This is not a debugging or why its not working problem if you read this question you can understand

Comment: "t when I want to quickly scroll the screen up, it tries to load all the data again" sounds like a problem in your implementation of scrolling up, which we can only help with if we see the minimal code that reproduces that problem. Instead of arguing that I didn't read your question, I recommend following my recommendation - which will give you a much better chance that someone can help.

Comment: I editted my question but my problem thats not implementing there is no option to add paginaiton for scrolling back to up thats why i asked

Comment: Your code only handles scrolling down, and in fact does so in a way that is better suited for a UI that displays a single page of results at a time allowing only going to the next page and never going to a previous page. To handle scrolling upward/paginating backwards, you'll want to have a look at the `endBeforeDocument` API which is the inverse of the `startAfterDocument` you now use.

Answer (score 1):

Your current code tracks the last document of the current results and then calls `startAfterDocument` with that document to get the next set of results. This works for scrolling forward, but not when scrolling backward. To paginate backwards, you'll also need to track the **first** document of the current results and then call `endBeforeDocument` with that document.